# Can you set an alias in webpack which will replace all matching occurrences in all files and not just requires?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to configure my react app for easy branding and styling,

there are some hardcoded branding strings which I don't want to use store for, and I don't want to have to pass properties through all components for branding. But I'd like to be able to change some of the strings globally at a whim.

I've used webpack alias' to make requiring and importing easier, but this doesn't seem to work for text within a react component render function, say setting

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~~BRAND_NAME': 'something'
  }
}
```

then

```
render() { 
  return <div> ~~BRAND_NAME </div>
}
```

being compiled to

```
render() {
  return <div> something </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a job for [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
    'BRAND_NAME': 'Some brand name'  // not sure about "~" working, but you can try 
  }),
],
```

then in the app you just reference it as a global variable:

```
render() { 
  return <div>{BRAND_NAME}</div>
}
```

Comment: this only works for variables right? Is there a way to replace any key string in any file parsed by webpack? Say even in index.html which doesn't use react?

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack Define plugin for this

in your webpack config file, in plugin section, add this

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'BRAND_NAME': JSON.stringify('something')
})
```

Then in your app render function, put the variable name in curly brackets

```
 return <h1>{BRAND_NAME}</h1>
```

More info on this [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Comment: this only works for variables right? Is there a way to replace any key string in any file parsed by webpack? Say even in index.html which doesn't use react?

Comment: U can use htmldefine plug in for that